# text/plain mimetype being set to "Python File (no console)"

Tags: python, wine, text, file-associations

After installing Wine and Python 2.7 in Wine, and then removing Wine, the plain text file format cannot be changed away from `Python File (no console)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `~/.local/share/mime/packages/x-wine-extension-*`, specifically `~/.local/share/mime/packages/x-wine-extension-pyw.xml`, fixed the issue.